# UL - 3 li - Middle li always center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a question (capt obvious..)

I have this html:

```
<div id="row-01-separator">
    <ul>
        <li>d</li>
        <!-- -->
        <li><img src="img/scroll_one.png"></li>
        <!-- -->
        <li>d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the Middle `li` with the image can noz get a background-color. Just the first and last element should have a background-color.

I got this CSS code

```
#row-01-separator ul {
    height: 32px;
}

#row-01-separator ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%; 
    min-height:100%;
}

#row-01-separator ul li:first-child, #row-01-separator ul li:last-child {
    background-color: white;
    width: calc(50% - 38px);
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

And it work. But the Problem is `width: calc(50% - 38px);` This doesnt work in ie8.

Do you have another idea how can I do this. I know there is a solution with javascript and oneresize.

But maybe you have solution with pure `css/html` and no js and no `calc()`.

I set up something on CodePen. I think you can understand it better than: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yBxdq

**EDIT:**

I decided to do the javascript/jquery alternative. I set up something on codepen, maybe someone can use is it later: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tfqdL

Comment: I know you want to make your website "all browser friendly", but ie8? 2% in the world has used that browser last month. Don't spent to much time to making your website ie8 friendly. `width: 48%\0/ !important; /* IE 8-9 */` is not perfect if you want exactly 28 pixels, but it gets you close

Comment: @bbvanee i know ie8 is dead. (8.april(also my birthday^^)) but im learning css/html right now so i wanna know as many "possibilities" as i can.